# ImageViews in ListViews

Tags: android, listview, imageview

I have a question about `ImageViews` in a `ListView`.

I made a `ListView` and in every row I have 2 `TextViews` (`tvName` and `tvPrice`), I get values for `TextViews` from my DB, and an `ImageView` (`ivAvailability`) that shows if the item is available (green circle - available, red circle - unavailable) and images in use are stored in the `res/drawable` folder. I have also implemented GCM service and I am using it to update the `ImageViews` when the availability of an item changes.

Example: I have 3 items in my `ListView` (`item1`, `item2`, `item3`). We find out that we ran out of `item3` so we want to update the picture from green circle to the red one. In my GCM message I have a int value (0 if not available and 1 if available) and I want the `ImageView` to change accordingly.

In my `ListActivity` I receive the GCM message with a `BroadcastReceiver`

```
private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String item = intent.getStringExtra("item");
        int id = intent.getIntExtra("id", 0); // 0 => id's default value
        int available = intent.getIntExtra("available", 0); // 0 => availability's default value

        Log.d(TAG, "Item: " + item);
        Log.d(TAG, "ID: " + id);
        Log.d(TAG, "Availability: " + availability);

        updateView(id, availability);

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};
```

And here is my `updateView` method

```
private void updateView(int id, int availability){
    View v = lvItem.getChildAt(id);
    if(v == null) return;

    switch (availability){
        case 0:
            //here i want to call the imageView in the respected row (example in row 3) and
            //change it with something like `setImageResource(R.drawable.traffic_red);`
            break;
        case 1:
            //here i want to call the imageView in the respected row (example in row 3) and
            //change it with something like `setImageResource(R.drawable.traffic_green);`
            break;
    }

}
```

My `GenericViewHolder.java`

```
public class GenericViewHolder {
    public View root;
    public TextView[] stringFields;
    public ImageView[] staticImageFields;
    public View[] baseFields;
}
```

My `getView()` method

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    // Inflate a new view or use a recycled view.
    View v = convertView;
    GenericViewHolder holder;

    if (null == v) {
        LayoutInflater vi =
                (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(mLayoutResource, null);
        holder = new GenericViewHolder();
        holder.root = v;
        // init the sub views and put them in a holder instance
        CustomAdapterUtils.initViews(v, holder, mBindDictionary);

        v.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (GenericViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }

    // Show the data
    final T item = getItem(position);
    showData(item, holder, position);

    return v;
}
```

And the xml file of an Item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:id="@+id/tvName"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:text="Large Text" />

 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/tvPrice"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvName"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ivTrafficLight"
    android:contentDescription=""
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
```

I am using [this](https://github.com/amigold/FunDapter) (FunDapter) lib.

So my question is how can I find the `ImageView` in the 3rd row? I tried `findViewById(R.id.ivAvailability)` but this always changes the `ImageView` in the top row not the one I would want to. So how do i distinct them from oneanother?

Comment: You tried `v.findViewById(R.id.ivAvailability)`?

Comment: You have to associate an id attribute with your list elements same as what you will be receiving from your gcm and also you have to treat that id as position from your listview. Get the item of that position and update it

Comment: use v.findViewById(R.id.ivAvailability) to get 3rd row imageview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I didn't see code of your Adapter, but anyway it's a good idea to use ViewHolder inner class in Adapters.

```
public static class ViewHolder {
    public ImageView imageView;
}
```

Then, in your getView method you can do something like that:

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder _viewHolder;
        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = _layLayoutInflater.inflate(_resourceID, parent, false);
            _viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            _viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_image);

            convertView.setTag(_viewHolder);
        }
        else
            _viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        return convertView;
    }
```

After all, when you do `View v = lvItem.getChildAt(id);` make following:

```
Adapter.ViewHolder viewHolder = (Adapter.ViewHolder) v.getTag();
viewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(...)
```

Try, hope it helps.

**Update.** Ok, both of this is working for me.
1.

```
YourAdapter.GenericViewHolder vh = (YourAdapter.GenericViewHolder) v.getTag();
vh.someTextField.setText("bbbbb");
```

2.

```
TextView t = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.your_item);
t.setText("abracadabra");
```

Please try firstly with text boxes, then with image containers. Thanks.
**PS.** Both worked without calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: I think `Adapter.ViewHolder viewHolder = (Adapter.ViewHolder) v;` should be `Adapter.ViewHolder viewHolder = (Adapter.ViewHolder) v.getTag();`

Comment: Sure, you right, thanks! Lost it while copying somehow. Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, but that wont work for me. I will add the `GenericViewHolder` class and my `getView` method.

Comment: Ok I figured it out and it works (just had to make some minor changes) :D Thank you very much for the help, I'll accept your answer

Answer (score 0):

View v = lvItem.getChildAt(id); this will return you the particular row item.

You can get the imageview on the row item as below

```
v.findViewById(R.id.ivAvailability);
```